# "Undoing" a nested tibble created with stringr::str_split

Tags: r, tidyr, stringr

I have created a nested tibble in R using `stringr::str_split`. Is there a more elegant way to go from the nested tibble to the "original" tibble than the solution I have presented below?

```r
library(tidyverse)
# original tibble
df <- tibble(x = c("a", "b"),
             y = c("a1, a2", "b1, b2"))
df
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   x     y     
#>   <chr> <chr> 
#> 1 a     a1, a2
#> 2 b     b1, b2

# nested version
df_nested <- df %>% 
  mutate(y = str_split(y, ", "))
df_nested
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   x     y        
#>   <chr> <list>   
#> 1 a     <chr [2]>
#> 2 b     <chr [2]>

# to get back to original
mutate(df, y = unlist(lapply(y, paste0, collapse = ", ")))
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   x     y     
#>   <chr> <chr> 
#> 1 a     a1, a2
#> 2 b     b1, b2
```

<sup>Created on 2019-01-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `map` from `purrr`

```
library(tidyverse)
df_nested %>% 
     mutate(y = map_chr(y, toString))
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#  x     y     
#  <chr> <chr> 
#1 a     a1, a2
#2 b     b1, b2
```

---

Also, both the steps can be done with `tidyverse` in another way with `separate_rows` and `group_by`, `summarise`

```
df %>% 
  separate_rows(y) %>% # long format
  group_by(x) %>% 
  summarise(y = toString(y)) # wide format
```